# Banco MySql não conecta com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Galera to tentando conectar um  banco MySql com c# por meio do Entity Framework, mas sempre que clico no botão avançar não dá em nada(com Sql Server vai o problema é com MySql)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa sua connectionString esta no padrão do MySql? tente: `server=localhost;database=biblioteca;uid=root;pwd=<senharoot>`;

Comment: veja a documentação https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html